# Concatenate external variable into Select Statement with no. of TABS based on length of external variable

Tags: oracle, select

Could someone please help with this requirement.

```
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT FAILURE
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE FAILURE
SET newpage none
SET trimspool ON
SET feedback OFF verify OFF tab OFF echo OFF termout OFF heading OFF
spool &1 append
SELECT
               '&3'
                ||CHR(9)
                ||':'
                ||CHR(9)
                ||COUNT (task_type)
FROM
        &2
WHERE
        task_type NOT LIKE '%SMART Table%'
AND     task_type NOT LIKE '%Sub-Table%';

spool OFF
EXIT;
```

I am running the above SQL query against a ORACLE DB from a bash script. There is a FOR loop which passes the value of '&3' to this query and then I concatenate it with corresponding value from the DB. The above query works perfectly fine. The issue I am facing is when &3 is >8 Characters, the formatting gets messed up. See below query output . When &3 was 'GSYS-PPTE' the single CHR(9) set it off from the other &3 values which are <8 Characters.

```
---------------------------------------
| AJD Total Tasks Count - DataCenters |
---------------------------------------
cmdev   :   14834
TSYSY   :   208
TSYSW   :   15
TSYSP   :   416
TSYSG   :   417
TSYSB   :   328
TSYS2   :   78
NOR2    :   46
MLCB    :   42
cmtest  :   5196
GSYS-PPTE   :   15
```

How do I add a logic to this query wherein if &3 is <8 Characters, 2 CHR(9)s are added to the select query else only 1 CHR(9) is added

Note : I have made a number of futile attempts at working this out. One of them below. I get compilation errors

```
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT FAILURE
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE FAILURE
SET newpage none
SET trimspool ON
SET feedback OFF verify OFF tab OFF echo OFF termout OFF heading OFF
spool &1 append
declare
dcname varchar2(12);
BEGIN
        SELECT
                '&3'
        INTO
                :dcname
        FROM
                dual;
        
        IF LENGTH(dcname) >= '8' THEN
                SELECT
                        '&3'
                                ||CHR(9)
                                ||':'
                                ||CHR(9)
                                ||COUNT (task_type)
                FROM
                         &2
                WHERE
                        task_type NOT LIKE '%SMART Table%'
                AND     task_type NOT LIKE '%Sub-Table%';
        
        ELSE
                SELECT
                        '&3'
                                ||CHR(9)
                                ||CHR(9)
                                ||':'
                                ||CHR(9)
                                ||COUNT (task_type)
                FROM
                        A210822PPT_AJOB
                WHERE
                        task_type NOT LIKE '%SMART Table%'
                AND     task_type NOT LIKE '%Sub-Table%';
        
        END IF;
END
spool OFF
EXIT;
```

Comment: Take a look at the `rpad` function: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/RPAD.html#GUID-064CFCAE-5902-49F9-800E-0AF311AEF595

Comment: @MarkStewart - My apologies I thought I had responded to you.
Thanks a lot, the RPAD option you suggested worked like a charm for me

Comment: You can add your solution as an answer, submit it, and accept your own answer.  This helps folks looking for unsolved issues.  Glad that helped.